# Exponential distribution conditioned with $V(X)=\infty$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, exponential-distribution

Let $X\sim \text{Exp}(\lambda), \lambda <0$. $Y$ conditional on $X=x$ is exponential distributed with parameter $\sqrt x$. Calculate $E(Y)$ and show $V(Y)=\infty$.

My attempt $E(Y)=E(E(Y\mid X=x))=\frac {1}{\sqrt x}$

But I do not see how to handle the second part now. I see that it is sufficient to show $E(Y^2)=\infty$ since $V(Y)=E(Y^2)-E(Y)^2=E(Y^2)-\frac 1x$, some help is welcome!

Comment: Look for law of total variance. Also, I do not think that your E[Y] is correct.

Comment: $\mathsf E(Y\mid X)=1/\surd X$, so $\mathsf E(Y)=\mathsf E(1/\surd X)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you start with : $$\begin{align}\mathsf E(Y) &=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(Y\mid X)) \\ &=\int_\Bbb R \mathsf E(Y\mid X=x) ~f_{X}(x)~\mathsf d x\\ & = \int_0^\infty \frac 1{\surd x}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}~\mathsf d x\end{align}$$

---

Approach through the Law for Total Variance: $$\mathsf{Var}(Y)=\mathsf E(\mathsf {Var}(Y\mid X))+\mathsf {Var}(\mathsf E(Y\mid X))$$